# Register set required for Threads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

My question is if a thread requires its own register set then how many threads can be created at the same time as register set present in a CPU is limited?

Comment: Lots, because when the OS switches threads, it stashes the registers for the previous thread elsewhere...

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

Comment: The thread context storage is very small potatoes compared to the address space required for the user and kernel mode stacks, north of a megabyte.  A 32-bit process tends to run out of it at a bit more than 2000 threads.  Many more in a 64-process, usually limited by pagefile size restrictions.  Fits the usual "if you need to know then you are doing it wrong" diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

A processor has a set of general registers that are shared by all threads/processes.

Most processors have Save and Load Process Context instructions that save (or load) the registers to/from a block of memory. The act of loading the process context into registers is what switches processes/threads.